# MVC Two ListBox's Adding from first to second on doubleclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-5

I have two ListBoxes that in my view. At the minute I have it working so that when one of the two buttons are pressed then the selected element is moved to the other list box. 
I would like to in addition to that, have it so that if one of the elements is Doubleclicked it moves to the other listbox.

This is the code in the view

```
<div class="PageRegionRole">
           @Html.Label("Available Roles", new { id = "Label1" })
           @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedRoleID, new SelectList(Model.StaffRoleList, "Value", "Text"), new { id = "LeftBox" })
              <div>
                  <input type="button" id="left" value="<<" />
                  <input type="button" id="right" value=">>" />
              </div>
           @Html.Label("Current Roles", new { id = "Label2" })
           @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedRoleID, Model.StaffRole, new { id = "RightBox" })            
</div>
```

This is the code i have in the js file for it

```
$(function () {
    $("#left").bind("click", function () {
        var options = $("[id*=RightBox] option:selected");
        for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
            var opt = $(options[i]).clone();
            $(options[i]).remove();
            $("[id*=LeftBox]").append(opt);
        }
    });


    $("#right").bind("click", function () {
        var options = $("[id*=LeftBox] option:selected");
        for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
            var opt = $(options[i]).clone();
            $(options[i]).remove();
            $("[id*=RightBox]").append(opt);
        }
    });
});
```

I've been at it for a while Now. I know I'm probably missing something obvious but its annoying me now.

Any Help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Just use the double click event. http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/

Comment: I know that using the double click event is the way to go but I can't for the life of me get it to work. It's driving me mad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your can simplify your existing scripts to

```
$("#left").click(function () {
  $('#RightBox').append($('#LeftBox').children(':selected'));
});
$("#right").click(function () {
  $('#LeftBox').append($('#RightBox').children(':selected'));
});
```

To transfer an option from one select to the other when an option is double clicked

```
$("#LeftBox").on('dblclick', 'option', function () {
    $('#RightBox').append($(this));
})
$("#RightBox").on('dblclick', 'option', function () {
    $('#LeftBox').append($(this));
})
```

Note also you have 2 select controls bound to the same property and will generate the same `<select name="SelectedRoleID" ...>` so this wont post back correctly. You should bind each to a different property (in which case, just use the ID's generated by the html helper). You are also using `@Label("Available Roles")` which is not creating a true label element since its not associated with the control. Use `@LabelFor(m => m.SelectedRoleID)`.